# How to split a dataframe based on specific texts of specific column

Tags: r

My dataframe is someting like this:

```
view(df)

    Case     Temp     Wind     Comment            Play
1   Train      30     false     Test               yes
2   Test       40     false     Recommended        no
3   Test       25     true      Sample             no
```

I want to split this dataframe into two dataframes test & train based on the string from 'Case' column.

I tried with

```
train <- split(df, df$Case)['Train']
test <- split(df, df$Case)['Test']
```

But, it didn't work. What's the way of it?

Comment: If you have only 'Test' and 'Train' in the data why not `train <- subset(df, Case == 'Train')` and `test <- subset(df, Case == 'Test')` Or using `split` : `dfList <- split(df, df$Case)` then do 
`train <- dfList[['Train']]` and `test <- dfList[['Test']]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proper way to do using list can be using double `[]` like this:

```
#Code
train <- split(df,df$Case)[['Train']]
test <- split(df,df$Case)[['Test']]
```

Or in a more practical way:

```
#Code2
list2env(split(df,tolower(df$Case)),envir = .GlobalEnv)
```

The outputs in both cases will be:

```
train
   Case Temp  Wind Comment Play
1 Train   30 false    Test  yes

test
  Case Temp  Wind     Comment Play
2 Test   40 false Recommended   no
3 Test   25  true      Sample   no
```

Some data used:

```
#Data
df <- structure(list(Case = c("Train", "Test", "Test"), Temp = c(30L, 
40L, 25L), Wind = c("false", "false", "true"), Comment = c("Test", 
"Recommended", "Sample"), Play = c("yes", "no", "no")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3"))
```

Answer (score 0):

This can also be done very simply using `dplyr`, which returns a list of data frames:

```
df_new = df %>% 
    dplyr::group_split(Case)
```

Gives

```
> df_new[1]
<list_of<
  tbl_df<
    Case   : character
    Temp   : integer
    Wind   : character
    Comment: character
    Play   : character
  >
>[1]>
[[1]]
# A tibble: 2 x 5
  Case   Temp Wind  Comment     Play 
  <chr> <int> <chr> <chr>       <chr>
1 Test     40 false Recommended no   
2 Test     25 true  Sample      no
```